# Execute a function after a map function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I have this code

```
$scope.items.map(function (item) {
   if(item.keywords.indexOf($scope.formData.keyword) != -1){
       array.push(bono);
   }
})
```

And I need to execute a function with all the elements of the array when the map finish. How can I do this? I thought to stack the calls but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Just put it on the next line.

Comment: It's angular, it's asynchronous :(

Comment: What exactly is asynchronous in this code? What type is `$scope.items`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As soon as `$scope.items` is an array as you stated in the question and the `Array.prototype.map()` is synchronous - which means that you simply put the next statement after this code and it will be executed after the `.map()` has completed processing.

Comment: Thank you, I thought it was asynchronous and I need to control that.

Answer (score 4):

We can use Promise.all() function:

```
var promises = [obj1, obj2,objN].map(function(obj){
  return database.query('id').then(function(results){
     return results;
  })
})
Promise.all(promises).then(function(results) {
    console.log("Result",results);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var array = [];
$scope.items.map(function (item) {
   if(item.keywords.indexOf($scope.formData.keyword) != -1){
       array.push(item);
   }
});

myFunction(array);
```

`Array.map()` documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: OP's questions does not look like async code. Why the down-vote?

Comment: @DavidLuque to be clear - this is exactly what I suggested: `mapFinished` makes no sense here, just put your next code next line.

Comment: @zerkms I put the mapFinished just so to be clear that .map() returns someting (an array).

Comment: @CristianSmocot and what is the point for that? `.map()` **ALWAYS** returns something. So `if (mapFinished)` check is **ALWAYS** true.

Comment: @zerkms In other words, myFunction(array) will always be executed.

Comment: That's correct. And my question is still here: **WHY** do you even have `if(true)` there? What is the point for that?

Comment: @CristianSmocot: yes. Meaning that your check only complicates the code and confuses readers.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev But you have to admit the the OP's questions is not very clear. My response was aimed at him understanding that .map() returns something and that his code is synchronous.

Comment: Your answer is misleading and confusing.

Comment: It still has the misleading and confusing code, even after update.

Comment: @CristianSmocot: just remove the original version of the code. It serves no purpose.

Comment: @zerkms: how is it misleading after the update? It's the same as your answer, only expressed in code, not words, no?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev now it's fine. I've left my comment when there still were 2 samples, one of which made no sense.

Answer (score -3):

try like this

```
$scope.items.map(function (item) {
   if(item.keywords.indexOf($scope.formData.keyword) != -1){
       array.push(bono);
   }
}).then(function(){}).then(function(){});
```

Comment: Does `.map` return a promise?

Comment: It does not answer my question. **WHY** do you think `.map()` function here returns a promise?

Comment: It's say me than .then is not a function

Comment: @DavidLuque all these 3 answers are completely rubbish, if you answered my question about `items` type it would be much more helpful.